# Cannot download Express Node JS

Tags: node.js

I have already successfully downloaded node.js.  I am getting error messages when attempting to download Express module.  Please can someone advise?

cmd display:

```
 C:\testapps>npm install --save express
 npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
 npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program 
 Files\\nodejs\\
 node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save" "express"
 npm ERR! node v6.11.2
 npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
 npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
 npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
 npm ERR! syscall connect

 npm ERR! Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 151.101.184.162:443
 npm ERR!     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
 npm ERR!     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1043:20)
 npm ERR!     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1086:14)
 npm ERR!  { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 151.101.184.162:443
 npm ERR!     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
 npm ERR!     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1043:20)
 npm ERR!     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1086:14)
 npm ERR!   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
 npm ERR!   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
 npm ERR!   syscall: 'connect',
 npm ERR!   address: '151.101.184.162',
 npm ERR!   port: 443 }
 npm ERR!
 npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
 npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

 npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
 npm ERR!     C:\testapps\npm-debug.log
```

My package.json file:

```
 {
   "name": "testapps",
   "version": "1.0.0",
   "private": true,
   "description": "meraki test",
   "main": "app.js",
   "scripts": {
   "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
 },
   "author": "",
   "license": "ISC",
   "dependencies":{
    "express": "4.15.4"
  }
 }
```

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? if so you will have to configure as following:
https://jjasonclark.com/how-to-setup-node-behind-web-proxy/

Comment: Antivirus-software or firewall blocking the request?

Comment: install it using npm install express --save or otherwise npm install -g express

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install Express in the current directory and save it in the dependencies list. For example:

```
npm install express --save
```

To install Express temporarily and not add it to the dependencies list:

```
npm install express --no-save
```

You can also install modules globally with:

```
npm install express -g
```

which allows you to access them without having to worry about your node directory, although these are then more difficult to manage and "you should try to avoid if you can".

From the Node Blog:

> Just like how global variables are kind of gross, but also necessary
>   in some cases, global packages are important, but best avoided if not
>   needed.
>
> In general, the rule of thumb is:
>
> If you’re installing something that you want to use in your program,
>   using require('whatever'), then install it locally, at the root of
>   your project. If you’re installing something that you want to use in
>   your shell, on the command line or something, install it globally, so
>   that its binaries end up in your PATH environment variable.

you can also install it with

`npm install express@4.15.4`

In later versions of express comand line was migrated to a separate module: express-generetor

use

```
npm install -g express-generator@4.15.0
```

check express with an example say `server.js`

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World')
})

app.listen(3000)
```

Run the server as `node server.js` and in browser check `http://localhost:3000`

Comment: i am sorry, i do not understand this answer.  I know how to go about installing express but I am getting the errors above.  How do I not get the errors above?

Comment: i have tried all the methods you mentioned.  Do you have an other suggestions?

Comment: check Where your node_modules are storing ???? change C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules to C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm \node_modules

Comment: you don't think my problem is with the proxy?